# AWS Sagemaker Multiple Object Detection in Image Recognition / Classification

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, computer-vision, amazon-rekognition, amazon-sagemaker

Does anyone know if any SageMaker built-in algorithm supports multiple object detection in image recognition? I am thinking something like multi-label image training and detection / inference.

Thus, can we:

**a) train using multi-label images**

and/or

**b) infer multiple objects from images (sort of like AWS Rekognition but with custom labels and training / transfer learning).**

Also, I know that the doc for SageMaker Image Classification Algorithm says "takes an image as input and classifies it into **one** of multiple output categories".

Any recommendations are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new built-in algorithm released with Amazon Sagemaker today for object detection. Based on the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/object-detection.html), Amazon SageMaker Object Detection uses the Single Shot multibox Detector (SSD) algorithm. The response from the inference contains an array consists of a predicted class label of the object detected, associated confidence score and bounding box co-ordinates.

Comment: Wow, that’s awesome! I’ll definitely check that out (sounds like exactly what I was looking for). Thank you

Comment: The Sagemaker object detection seem to be very similar to AWS Image Rekognition. Do you know the difference between the two and use-cases for each?

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE: Checkout [Object Detection Algorithm in SageMaker](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/object-detection-algorithm-now-available-in-amazon-sagemaker/)

---

SageMaker's [image classification algorithm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/image-classification.html) takes in an image and returns a collection of class and probability.
To classify multiple objects in an image, you need to pre-process the image to *detect* objects, resulting in multiple smaller images with one object per image, which you'll provide as input to the [image classification algorithm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/image-classification.html).

Typically [*object detection* is an easier task than *object identification/classification*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662299/object-recognition-vs-detection-vs-classification-whats-the-difference).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know of any way to use built-in SageMaker tools to accomplish this? Or do I need to implement an object detection algorithm on my own (I am assuming like YOLO or faster r-cnn, etc?)

Comment: Yes. Any detection framework that can put bounding boxes on objects. You can deploy this custom detection model on SageMaker, by packaging it on a docker container. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms.html

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that this would be possible using a built-in algorithm; I guess not.

Comment: Nice Siraj overview video on using YOLO: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eIBisqx9_g&t=771s

Comment: @dima Checkout https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/object-detection-algorithm-now-available-in-amazon-sagemaker/